# Do birds flock?

Tags: terraria

I was building my storage unit for my new building and I found a big group of birds all flying together. Is this normal?[image]

Comment: In case this helps, there were 4 owls, 2 cardinals, and 2 blue jays.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, think I figured out why. They aren't flocking, they're just stuck between a mountain and my house, and can't fly higher than my building to get out.